# Filtering one JSON attribute against another with Lodash or Angular

Tags: json, lodash

I'm looking for the fastest and most elegant way to do this. I've seen similar questions asked and they're all very specific to a problem. I'm fairly new with Lodash, and I've used _.find mostly. I'm not sure how to use _.filter to get what I want, a new JSON array with just the filtered returns:

The array I'm filtering from:

```
var mod1 = [{"Codigo" : "001", "Valor" : "Rojo"},
                {"Codigo" : "002", "Valor" : "Blue"},
                {"Codigo" : "003", "Valor" : "Grey"},
                {"Codigo" : "004", "Valor" : "Green"},
                {"Codigo" : "005", "Valor" : "Pink"},
                {"Codigo" : "006", "Valor" : "Gold"},
                {"Codigo" : "007", "Valor" : "Black"},
                {"Codigo" : "008", "Valor" : "White"},
                {"Codigo" : "009", "Valor" : "Magenta"},
                {"Codigo" : "010", "Valor" : "Marine Blue"},
                {"Codigo" : "011", "Valor" : "Orange"}];
```

My function in the controller, with prod being a single product's JSON, which contains 5 modifiers. A complete list like the above for each modifier is stored locally, while another is received to be filtered from through a webservice. The values to be filtered out are simply the "Codes", and the string I receive from the webservice are a string separated by commas.

```
$scope.mod11 = Productos.getMod1(prod.mod1);
```

What I actually receive to filter with looks like this:

```
"mod1":"001, 002, 005"
```

And this is my terrible attempt at filtering:

```
getMod1: function(mods) {
            return _.filter(mod1, angular.fromJson(mods));
            /*return mod1;*/
        }
```

I've tried it a few different ways, including doing a split(',) on the mods. I just need to bring back all of of the Codigo == any value in the string.

**EDIT:** Final outcome I'm looking  for in this particular case is looks like this for $scope.mod11

```
[{"Codigo" : "001", "Valor" : "Rojo"}, 
 {"Codigo" : "002", "Valor" : "Blue"},
 {"Codigo" : "005", "Valor" : "Pink"}]
```

Comment: What should be the final outcome?

Comment: Final outcome in scope.mod11 should be = [{"Codigo" : "001", "Valor" : "Rojo"}, {"Codigo" : "002", "Valor" : "Blue"},{"Codigo" : "005", "Valor" : "Pink"}] in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegant solution using lodash  [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and  [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs#includes):

```
var codes = "001, 002, 005".split(', ');

getMod1: function(){
    return _.filter(mod1, function(c){
        return _.includes(codes, c.Codigo);
    })
}
```

Comment: Two good answers solving the same problem. Thank you both very much.

Comment: Just as a note for anyone seeing this in the future, if you want a complete answer you do have to take any possible spaces from the string first: 
    var array = mods.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',');

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding:

```
var mod1 = [{"Codigo" : "001", "Valor" : "Rojo"},
                {"Codigo" : "002", "Valor" : "Blue"},
                {"Codigo" : "003", "Valor" : "Grey"},
                {"Codigo" : "004", "Valor" : "Green"},
                {"Codigo" : "005", "Valor" : "Pink"},
                {"Codigo" : "006", "Valor" : "Gold"},
                {"Codigo" : "007", "Valor" : "Black"},
                {"Codigo" : "008", "Valor" : "White"},
                {"Codigo" : "009", "Valor" : "Magenta"},
                {"Codigo" : "010", "Valor" : "Marine Blue"},
                {"Codigo" : "011", "Valor" : "Orange"}];

var response = {mod1: "001, 002, 005"};
var keys = response.mod1.split(', ');
var arr =[];
for(var i=0;i<mod1.length;i++){
  if (keys.indexOf(mod1[i].Codigo) > -1) {
    arr.push(mod1[i])
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Output:

```
Run in console.
```

Comment: My apologies. I edited my post to specify the output I'm looking for.

Comment: See my updated answer without using Lodash, it's simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest is @softvar's solution.
If you're looking for elegance, might be this:

```
var codes = "001, 002, 005".split(', ');
var mods = _(mod1).indexBy("Codigo").pick(codes).values().value();
```